# Guaranteeing `RETURNING` from an upsert while limiting what data is stored

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE scoped_data(
  owner_id text,
  scope text
  key text,
  data json,
  PRIMARY KEY (owner_id, scope, key)
);
```

As part of each transaction we will *potentially* be inserting data for multiple scopes. Given this table has the potential to grow very quickly I would like not to store `data` if it is `NULL` or an empty JSON object.

An upsert felt like the idiomatic approach to this. The following is within the context of a PL/pgSQL function:

```
WITH upserts AS (
  INSERT INTO scoped_data (owner_id, scope, key, data)
    VALUES
      (p_owner_id, 'broad', p_broad_key, p_broad_data),
      (p_owner_id, 'narrow', p_narrow_key, p_narrow_data),
      -- etc.
    ON CONFLICT (owner_id, scope, key)
      DO UPDATE SET data = scoped_data.data || COALESCE(EXCLUDED.data, '{}')
    RETURNING scope, data
)
SELECT json_object_agg(u.scope, u.data)
  FROM upserts u
  INTO v_all_scoped_data;
```

I include the `RETURNING` as I would like the up-to-date version of each scope's data included in a variable for subsequent use, therefore I need the `RETURNING` to return something even if logically no data has been updated.

For example (all for `key = 1 and scope = 'narrow'`):

1. `data = '{}'` => `v_scoped_data = {}`, no data for `key = 1` in `scoped_data`.
2. `data = '{"some":"data"}'` => `v_scoped_data = { "narrow": { "some": "data" } }`, data present in `scoped_data`.
3. `data = '{}'` => `v_scoped_data = { "narrow": { "some": "data" }`, data from 2. remains unaffected.
4. `data = '{"more":"stuff"}'` => `v_scoped_data = { "narrow": { "some": "data", "more": "stuff" }`. Updated data stored in table.

I initially added a trigger `BEFORE INSERT ON scoped_data` which did the following:

```
IF NULLIF(NEW.data, '{}') IS NULL THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
```

This worked fine for preventing the insertion of *new* records but the issue was that this trigger also prevented subsequent inserts to *existing* rows thereby no `INSERT` happened therefore there was no `ON CONFLICT` therefore nothing returned in the `RETURNING`.

A couple of approaches I've considered, both of which feel inelegant or like they should be unnecessary:

- Add a `CHECK` constraint to `scoped_data.data`: `CHECK(NULLIF(data, '{}') IS NOT NULL)`, allow the insert and catch the exception in the PL/pgSQL code.
- `DELETE` in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger if the `data` field was `NULL` or empty.

Am I going about this in the right way? Am I trying to coerce this logic into an upsert when there is a better way? Might explicit `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s be a more logical fit?

I am using **Postgres 9.6**.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the `BEFORE` trigger `ON INSERT` to prevent unnecessary inserts and updates.

To return the values even in the case that the operation is not performed, you can `UNION ALL` your query with a query on `scoped_data` that returns the original row, `ORDER` the results so that any new row is ordered first (introduce an artifical column to both queries) and use `LIMIT 1` to get the correct result.